# How to hide ImageButton if android version is under "X"?

Tags: android, version-control, sdk, imagebutton

Actually i'm making an app for waiter in android, 
and when i waiter log-in i have two ImageButtons that permise to scan their badge, so i would be able to hide that ImageButtons if the version of android is <= 21.

How can i be able to make something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` . version for 21 is `LOLLIPOP`

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        //show button
    }else {
       // hide button
    }
```

make sure you use the following import

```
import android.os.Build;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
// above version of 21
} else{
// lowversion of 21
}
```